# Excel Detect PasteSpecial operation

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, vba, com

I'm working on a software that evaluate the skill of a user on Excel.
So the user do some operation within Excel, as asked in a series of question,
and my job is to program something to validate what the user have done, using Excel COM Object.
I'm able to validate thing like; Cell format, Cell Orientation, Print Area, Font Type, merged Cells, etc. But I'm struggling to validate the "Paste Special" operation.
I've a hook with the Change event of the WorkSheet and the WorkSheet itself. So I can catch what keyStroke the user have done and the the actual format of the cell. 
But I'm not able to find a way to tell if the user have used the "Format Only - Special Paste". Has anyone can help me on this?

Comment: if you are able to catch up the "record macro", you could write a logfile with it.... but thats just an idea and i dont know if and how that may be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect a "Paste Special" event by monitoring the Undo list through:

```
If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1) = "Paste Special" Then
```

Not necessary to check the actual keystrokes.

Sadly it doesn't offer any further detail of what type of paste special was performed. If you know the range (either predefined or through the `Target` in your `Workbook_SheetChange` event) you can then do an undo (`Application.Undo`), store the cell values before the paste, redo the paste at the Target. If the values have changed then it wasn't a "Format Only - Special Paste". Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank for your input, your suggestion in combination with a little cell hidden format like Custom Format "0,00E+00", will do the trick

Comment: Make sure you disable the detection of events (`Application.EnableEvents = False`) as soon as the worksheet change event fires because it will fire again as soon as your script pastes values to the cells. This will cause an infinite loop. Once you complete all you need then re-enable detection of events (`Application.EnableEvents = True`). Cheers,

Comment: Actually my script did not paste anything, it is just monitoring what the user is doing